# Computing $I'(x)$ of $I(x)=\int_{-\exp(x)}^{x^2}\cos(xt^2) dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$I(x)=\int_{-\exp(x)}^{x^2}\cos(xt^2) \mathrm dt,\qquad I: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

I want to determine $I'(x)$ **by hand**.

I thought about using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) (are there other ways?) and ended up with

$$I'(x)=\cos(x^5)2x-\cos(x(-\exp(x))^2)(-\exp(x)))+\int_{-\exp(x)}^{x^2}-\sin(xt^2)t^2dt$$

But this doesn't get me any further because I can't compute that last integral.
I would appreciate any tips/solutions.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This gives a Fresnel integral

Comment: Is there a "beautiful" solution to this task? Or am I finished? (I have to do this by hand)

Comment: Now I realized that you are actually asking how to integrate the last integral, not asking how to differentiate $I(x)$ using the chain-rule trick. As others pointed out, the last integral is related to Fresnel sine integral, and is known to have no closed form in terms of elementary functions. That being said, you are finished.

Comment: @SangchulLee My aim was/is to differentiate $I(x)$ but I ended up with that last integral so I asked how to integrate it. What chain-rule trick do you mean? Or do you mean the leibniz rule I used anyway?

Comment: Yes, Leibniz's integral rule is simply the result of chain rule applied to the function $G(x,a(x),b(x))$, where $$G(x,u,v)=\int_{u}^{v}f(x,t)\,dt.$$ That is why I called it a chain-rule trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $\int \sin(xt^2)t^2dt$, we have
$$\int \sin(xt^2)t^2dt\\
=\frac12\int\sin(xt^2)tdt^2\\
=\frac12\int\sin(xu)\sqrt udu\\
=\frac12(\frac{\cos(xu)\sqrt u}x-\frac12\int\frac{\cos(xu)}{x\sqrt u}du)$$
And $$\int \frac{\cos(y)}{\sqrt y}dy=\sqrt{2\pi}\operatorname{C}(\sqrt{\frac{2y}\pi })$$
(Where $\operatorname{C}$ denotes Fresnel C funtion)